# Password protect a folder and website shown on subdomain without dropping a file inside that folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

I have a website which has a folder structure like this:

```
public_html/mywebsite/
public_html/mywebsite/staging
public_html/mywebsite/production
```

mywebsite is a website which sells a product. staging and production are sub folders for the product.

I want to password protect with apache basic auth the staging folder.

Going to http://www.mywebsite.com shows the contents of public_html/mywebsite

Going to the subdomain http://staging.mywebsite.com shows the contents of public_html/mywebsite/staging

My question is can I password protect the staging website without putting any files in that folder?

The reason I don't want to put any files in the folder is that it automatically gets cloned to production every now and again and I don't want to put a .htaccess file in their which would get copied to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Put the rules in your main Apache config
- Update your cloning process to ignore .htaccess files

There's no other way unless you can just move the staging folder off your main website's folder structure.

Comment: Thanks sometimes it's the simple way is the best e.g. update the cloning process to take account of the difference in the .htaccess files and write out a different one for production without the .htaccess auth that staging has.